# How to use mutating member on immutable value?

Tags: ios, swift, mutating-function

I got the solution but can't understand why it works.

my struct is `QuizBrain()`

whenever i try to use this code, i got an error:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value

btw the `checkAnswer` method is mutated.

code:

```
let userGotItRight = QuizBrain().checkAnswer(pressedAnswer)
```

The solution is creating an object from that struct and using it. Can someone explain why it is necessary to create an object?

code:

```
var quizBrain = QuizBrain()

let userGotItRight = quizBrain.checkAnswer(pressedAnswer)
```

Comment: The difference lies between `var` and `let`. When you declare `var`, it can be mutated. `let` is constant hence cannot be mutated. Without assigning to a `var`, it is treated as a `let` constant because there isn't a "variable" to be mutated.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually mix of `let` vs `var` and `class` vs `struct`. Here are some examples. Firstly lets declare your code as both `struct` and `class`:

```
struct QuizBrainStruct {
    var answer: String?
    mutating func checkAnswer(_ str: String) {
        self.answer = str
    }
}

class QuizBrainClass {
    var answer: String?
    func checkAnswer(_ str: String) {
        self.answer = str
    }
}

let pressedAnswer = "pressed"
```

In this example we I will use `QuizBrainStruct()` and `QuizBrainClass()` which are similar but not the same.
Your `QuizBrain()` is defined as struct, therefore if you make this statement:

```
let userGotItRight = QuizBrainStruct().checkAnswer(pressedAnswer)// would fail with: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value is a 'let' constant
```

It is basicelly treated the same way as declaring `let` variable and then calling the function on in as following:

```
let s = QuizBrainStruct()
s.checkAnswer(pressedAnswer) // would fail with: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 's' is a 'let' constant
```

Your workoroud works if you declare it as a var, because values of var can be mutated:

```
var s2 = QuizBrainStruct()
s2.checkAnswer(pressedAnswer)
```

However there is more into the topic and that is that `Struct` is passed as value, therefore "s" cannot be mutated. If you declare it as a class (which is passed as reference) . You can do the following with no errors:

```
let userGotItRight = QuizBrainClass().checkAnswer(pressedAnswer)
```

Here is the difference why:

```
let s1 = QuizBrainStruct()
let s2 = s1 // s1 value is a new value and it is copy of s1

let c1 = QuizBrainClass()
let c2 = c1 // c1 value is reference to c1 (same value)
```

For more info about struct vs class you can read following [swift doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html) . You can read more about value and reference type here: [value vs reference passing](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10)